# Convergence of a series with a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which $a >0$ does series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+\cos\frac{1}{n})(-1)^{n+[a]}}{(1+\ln(n))^a} $$

converge?

I think I'm doing something wrong here but I can't see where.

Let's test convergence:

$$ \frac{(1+\cos\frac{1}{n})(-1)^{n+[a]}}{(1+\ln(n))^a} \leq \frac{2\cdot (-1)^{n+[a]}}{(1+\ln(n))^a} $$

because $\cos(x) \leq 1$. Since I'm only testing convergence here, and multiplying series by a constant doesn't change its convergence, I'll just divide this $2$ out.

Now I have

$$ \frac{(-1)^{n+[a]}}{(1+\ln(n))^a} $$

$ (-1)^{n+[a] } $ behaves almost identically to $ (-1)^{n} $ ( if $a$ is odd it just becomes $-(-1)^{n}$ which still will be alternating ones, so I can apply Leibniz's test.

Denominator goes to infinity as $n \rightarrow \infty $, so limit will be $0$. Now for monotonicness:

$$ \frac{1}{(1+\ln (n))^a} \geq \frac{1}{(1+\ln(n+1))^a} $$

$$ (1 + \ln(n+1))^a \geq (1 + \ln(n))^a $$

both sides are positive so I can take $a$th root

$$ \ln(n+1) \geq \ln(n) $$

This is true for positive $n$s, so the test is also true for them, so the series will always be convergent, independently of $a$?

Comment: For better typesetting use `\ln(x)` instead of just `ln(x)` (similar for other standard functions like `\exp`, `\cos` etc.). More info can be found on [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you want to apply Leibniz (which is a good idea here) you need to include the $1+\cos(1/n)$ term in the derivation, i.e. you need to check that $f(n) = \frac{1+\cos(1/n)}{(1+\ln(n))^a}$ is eventually monotone. Minor point: your first inequality does not make sense as the inequality $(1+\cos(1/n))(-1)^n \leq 2(-1)^n$ is not true when $n$ is odd. However this inequality is not relevant for the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the series converges no matter what $a>0$ is. But your proof is wrong: you cannot apply directly Leibniz's test (alternating series test) here. What you did is majoring the absolute value (your inequality is not true with the $(-1)^n$ still in there...), then apply the test to the upper bound you get: but this is not a legit thing to do, since convergence of the new series does not imply convergence of yours. (See in the comments below for a counter example.)

---

Another way:

First, note that
$$
\frac{(1+\cos\frac{1}{n})(-1)^{n+[a]}}{(1+\ln(n))^a}
= (-1)^{[a]}\frac{(1+\cos\frac{1}{n})(-1)^{n}}{(1+\ln(n))^a}
$$
so for the rest I'll ignore the factor $(-1)^{[a]}$, that has no influence whatsoever  on the convergence.

Since the series is alternating, a natural idea is to apply the alternating series test, which asserts that if $a_n$ is non-negative and non-increasing, converging to $0$, then the series $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$ converges. Sadly, the above series above does not satisfy the non-increasing part *a priori*. So we'll expand it into a first term that does, and a second that we are able to analyze using different tools:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1+\cos\frac{1}{n}}{{(1+\ln(n))^a}}
&=
\frac{2+\frac{1}{2n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{{(1+\ln(n))^a}} \\
&= 
\frac{2}{{(1+\ln(n))^a}}
+
\frac{1+o(1)}{{2n^2(1+\ln(n))^a}}\\
&= 
\frac{2}{{(1+\ln(n))^a}}
+
\frac{1+o(1)}{2n^2 \ln(n)^a}
\end{align}
$$
so that
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^n \frac{1+\cos\frac{1}{n}}{{(1+\ln(n))^a}}
&=
\frac{2(-1)^n}{{(1+\ln(n))^a}}
+
(-1)^n\frac{1+o(1)}{2n^2 \ln(n)^a}.
\end{align}
$$
Now, for any $a>0$:

- the first term is the general term of a convergent series, since we can now apply the alternating series test to it:  $\sum \frac{2(-1)^n}{{(1+\ln(n))^a}}$ is a convergent series
- the second term is absolutely convergent, e.g. by comparison to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

and therefore our original series converges as the sum of two convergent series, no matter what $a>0$ is.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I don't know nor can't use the trick you did with $ 1 + \cos \frac{1}{n} $, so I'll just trust you with this one working. May you, though, explain why the convergence of majorization of an absolute value of a series doesn't imply absolute convergence of original one? (I know that this one is not absolutely convergent, but I'm asking for general case - this seems like a thing I'd use without thinking about)

Comment: I do not have a clear counter-example, but let's but it differently: at a high-level, what you are saying is "$0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$, and $\sum(-1)^n b_n$ converges, therefore $\sum(-1)^n a_n$ converges." My gut feeling is that this is not true (since for instance nothings constraints $a_n$ to be non-increasing, which Leibniz's test relies on), but even if it is I don't see a simple one-line argument to justify it...

Comment: I think I'm saying that $ 0 \leq a_n \leq b_n $ where $ b_n $ is $ \sum (-1)^n c_n $, or am I not?

Comment: @BagofChips Note that the inequality as written in your post is wrong, you need to remove the $(-1)^n$ signs for it to be true... There is some generl fuzziness about the way you handle the alternating signs.

Comment: For a counterexample (re my previous comment), I think that taking $$a_n = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2n} & \text{ if } n \text{ odd }\\ \frac{1}{n} & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ works. You have $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$, and $(b_n)_n$ is decreasing to $0$ so that $\sum_n (-1)^n b_n$ converges by Leibniz's test, **but** the series $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$ does not converge (it diverges to $+\infty$).